# The difference between redirection with and without exec

Tags: bash, interprocess

Anyone clarify what the definitive difference between:

```
 3<&0
```

and

```
 exec 3<&0
```

of bash or other akin shell?
thanks before

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736230/307939

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that file descriptor `3` remains open after `exec 3<&0`. See:

```
$ cat foo
bar
$
$ 3<foo
$ cat <&3
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
$
$ exec 3<foo
$ cat <&3
bar
$
```